# HTTP Connection refused while connecting to a server

Tags: logging

I am using my Android device to talk to my *WAMP server* .

I am sending bits via`http` connection to a script on `/www/` directory.

But in *logcat*, I am getting the following error :

```
~error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException :Connection to xx.xx.xx.xx:8080  was refused ! ~
```

`xx.xx.xx.xx` is my IP address !

Help needed asap .

Thanks

Comment: What does your Apache log say about the connection attempt? What about the Windows Event logs? Can any other devices/web browsers "talk" to it?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

1. You can access to your server and port with your browser
2. Your emulator has 3G or WiFi enabled
3. Your emulator's browser can access to the server and port

Comment: I am using a real Droid and it is connected to the Internet ! please !

Comment: Can you access to the server and port in your Droid's browser? It could be your carrier's policy.

Comment: when people see 1 answer, they don't view the question !! Little do they realize that the answer was irrelevant to the question asked: One of the limitations of this site !

Comment: For heaven's sake ! There's no carrier policy ! and yes everything is perfect from the hardware point of view.. please refrain from answering please ! your answers are irrelevant .

Comment: I need to have the context in order to help you. Clearly the minutes I would have used in finding a solution to your problem, would have been more than those you use in testing and answering. If you're unable to realize this then I hope someone else can help. Good luck.

Comment: @Heather: The error message seems straightforward, and probably means exactly what it says: the server is refusing the connection.  I think this is one of those times where you're going to have to do some troubleshooting and figure out what the problem is.  I would eliminate the obvious things first.

Comment: Hi, I have been having this problem for the past 4 days.. I wanna know what configurations I need to change on my wamp . thanks

Comment: I know that the error message is clear ! what is wrong with everyone today ! Robert, please re read your answer and tell me how it is supposed to help me !

Comment: @Heather: None of us know what the problem is.  Tell you what, I will clean up some of these comments and migrate your question to the Android site; maybe someone there has some specialized knowledge we don't.

Answer (score 1):

Either your server is refusing connection or one of the routers between your phone and the server (e.g. your carrier's router) is refusing connection.

Try connecting to the server from another device (preferrably from a Wifi connection), if your connection is refused from that other device as well, then it is almost definitely a server configuration issue and this question should be asked on SuperUser or ServerFault.

Your question is way too vague to be answerable, you will need to answer these questions (hint: you can edit your question, then put a comment to notify your answerers):

1. There is no such thing as a device "talking" to another device. What do you mean by "talking" to the server? Is your server serving static HTML pages, CGI scripts, or is it some kind of media streaming server?
2. Is the IP address the server's local IP address (e.g. looks like 127.0.0.xxx or 192.168.xxx.xxx, or is it the server's public IP address?
3. Can you access this server from other devices? What have you tried?
4. How are you connecting to the serve from the Android? Is it over Wifi or over 3G?